# Avoid python loop in deleting error prone values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

My timelines are stored in simple numpy Arrays, and they are long (>10 Million entrys)

I have to detect machine shutdowns, that show in jumps in the time vector . After that shutdown I want do delete the next 10 values (The sensors do give bad results for a while after being switched on) and continue.

I came up with the following code:

```
Keep_data=np.empty_like(Timestamp_new,dtype=np.bool)                                
Keep_data[0]=False
Keep_data[1:]=Timestamp_new[1:]>(Timestamp_new[:-1]+min_shutdown_length)

for item in np.nonzero(np.logical_not(Keep_data))[0]:
    Keep_data[item:min(item+10,len(Keep_data)]=False

Timestampnew=Timestampnew[Keep_data]
```

Can anyone suggest a more effective code, without a pure python Loop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are trying to spread/grow or in image-processing terms [`dilate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) the `False` regions. For the same, we have a built-in as [`scipy's binary_dilation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html). Now, you are trying to make it grow starting from each such `False` element in input array `Keep_data` towards higher indices. So, we need to use a different offset (or as scipy calls it : `origin`) than the default one as `0`, which otherwise would have dilated across both ends for each element.

Thus, to sum up, an implementation with it to get rid of the loopy portion of the code, we would have an implementation like so -

```
N = 10   # Interval length
dilated_mask = binary_dilation(~Keep_data, structure=np.ones(N),origin=-int(N/2))
Keep_data[dilated_mask] = False
```

---

An alternative approach that would be closer to the one posted as the loopy code in the question, but vectorized with [`NumPy's broadcasting feature`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), would look something like this -

```
N = 10   # Interval length
idx = np.nonzero(np.logical_not(Keep_data[:-N]))[0]
Keep_datac[(idx + np.arange(N)[:,None]).ravel()] = False
rest = np.nonzero(np.logical_not(Keep_data[-N:]))[0]
if len(rest)>0:
    Keep_datac[-N+rest[0]:] = False
```

Comment: The fist solutuion seems to be slower than the original Version, but the second one works great for me. One downside is that the cliping is done with a

Comment: @user3373796 That clipping is needed to do the same job as your `min()`. What exactly is the downside with it?

Comment: The downside is that cliping is done on all values, if nessesary or not, not only on the last indices. But on second thought that is only 10%.
So very helpful answer.

Comment: @user3373796 Updated to avoid that clipping, with an IF statement. Hope this would be a bit faster. Check it out!

Comment: That just failed my test with small Errors in the corners, but being inspired by the idea, I came up with this:
`N = 10   # Interval length`

`idx = np.nonzero(np.logical_not(Keep_data[:-N]))[0]`

`if (np.logical_not(Keep_data[-N:]).any():`

`    Keep_data[np.nonzero(np.logical_not(Keep_data[:-N]))[0][0]:] = False`

`Keep_data[(idx + np.arange(N)[:,None])] = False`

`

Comment: @user3373796 Or another version of it, just added. If it solved your question, consider accepting it. Read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).